# Plotly output in Shiny "Error: argument 1 is not a vector"

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to make an interactive plot in my Shiny app. I thought it would be simple enough to use `plotly::plotlyOutput` and `plotly::renderPlotly`, but I keep getting `Error: argument 1 is not a vector`. I wonder if you can help?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

daysSince10 <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joegoodman94/CoronavirusTracker/master/days.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Coronavirus Tracker"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput('Country', 'Select Countries', multiple = T, unique(daysSince10$`Countries and territories`))),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", plotly::plotlyOutput('trend')),
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput('table'))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    moddays <- daysSince10[daysSince10$`Countries and territories` %in% input$Country,]
    output$trend <- plotly::renderPlotly({
      ggplot(moddays) +
        geom_line(aes(x = `Number of days since 10th death`, y = `Total Deaths`, color = `Countries and territories`)) +
        scale_y_log10()
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plot is working fine, the problem is when you lack any country to graph on it, here is a really cool solution using the validate function

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

daysSince10 <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joegoodman94/CoronavirusTracker/master/days.csv")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Coronavirus Tracker"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput('Country', 'Select Countries', multiple = T, unique(daysSince10$`Countries and territories`))),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", plotly::plotlyOutput('trend')),
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput('table'))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    moddays <- daysSince10[daysSince10$`Countries and territories` %in% input$Country,]
    output$trend <- plotly::renderPlotly({
      validate(
        need(input$Country, "please select a country")
      )

      ggplot(moddays) +
        geom_line(aes(x = `Number of days since 10th death`, y = `Total Deaths`, color = `Countries and territories`)) +
        scale_y_log10()
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Even with default selected value, there is a risk that no countries are ultimately selected. Using `req(input$Country)` inside `observe()` or using `validate()` seems more appropriate

Comment: No problem, you could add these alternatives in your answer

Comment: @Bruno I've now started to develop the table but am having a similar problem. I wonder if I'm missing anything? I tried both with and without the validate(need()) function... 

#In the UI I've got:

tabPanel("Table", DT::DTOutput('table')) 

#and the server:

output$table <- DT::renderDT({
      validate(
        need(input$Country, "please select a country")
      )      
      daysSince10()

#(the table should be just the data in the plot)

Comment: Probably better to post a new question